# Multiselect products to add directly to shopping cart

Tags: configurable-product, cart, extensions, addtocart, grouped-products

Would anyone have a recommendation on an extension that would allow the customer to add several products to their cart using one click.

My client sells paints and dyes and would like color swatches with editable quantities and sizes for each product that the customer can easily check off or input and drop into their shopping cart using 1 click. The ultimate goal is to display color and ordering options much like they are seen in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need extensions for this, use the **Grouped Product** product type.

Find documentation for grouped products here: http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-grouped.html